# Qual é o certo, estrutura de fluxo de controle ou de controle de fluxo? E por que fluxo, e por que controle?

Tags: terminologia, if, for, while, controle-de-fluxo

Há muito tenho o costume de chamar `if`, `for`, `while`, etc. de estruturas de controle de fluxo, o que sempre me pareceu fazer sentido, porque servem para controlar o fluxo de execução da aplicação.

Mas o nome certo ao que me parece é estruturas de [fluxo de controle (*control flow*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow), e não sei bem por quê.

Note que temos uma tag [controle-de-fluxo](/questions/tagged/controle-de-fluxo), cuja wiki fala de fluxo de controle.

Qual é o certo, e por quê?

Ainda, é possível dissecar este porquê? Por que fluxo, e por que controle?

Answer (score 4):

Como o programa executa?

Através de um fluxo de execução, certo?

Temos até algo chamado fluxograma.

O fluxo existe de várias formas, e o mais simples é a sequência, que não há controle algum, ele só vai.

Quando ele muda de direção ou de posição e interrompe a sequência?

Isso acontece em comandos especiais que controlam para onde o fluxo vai, mais ou menos como em uma linha de trem:

[image: Linha de trem sendo desviada]

Como chamamos aquilo que seguramos na mão para mandar o que os elementos de um vídeo-game devem fazer?

Chama controle, certo?

[image: Joystick]

Ele é um fluxo que controla algo ou é algo que controla o fluxo?

Se não o usar, o jogo para de ter fluxo?

Controle é uma chave que muda um estado, é algo que pode desviar o fluxo normal.

Procure a tradução de *control flow*. Encontrará o mesmo da nossa *tag*, certo?

Procure por *flow control*. Dá a mesma tradução.

*Flow of control* é que dá fluxo de controle.

A Wikipedia em português chama de Estrutura de Controle. Mas controle de que?

Eu já usei muito esse termo porque vi muito ele, mas não sei sequer se isso é uma estrutura. Não tem muito isso em inglês. Quem chama assim deveria justiciar, certo? Senão fica repetição do erro que alguém fez uma vez.

É mais ou menos como "lógica de programação" que você não encontra justificativa ou definição do que é (eu pesquisei e não tem nem nos livros que tem a expressão no título, eles definiem o que é um algoritmo).

O verbete nas duas línguas aceita secundariamente como fluxo de controle. É certo? Pode ser, mas lá não tem justificativa. A Wikipedia não é o local onde está a verdade. Lá *pode* estar a verdade.

Se as duas formas estão no verbete, provavelmente você pode usar as duas e ninguém poderá falar que você está errado, e isso é o que mais importa.

Já que isso é mais linguístico, apesar de ser de grande interesse de programadores, até para tomar decisões corretas, eventualmente, pegando outro exemplo, em inglês *story* e *history* são palavras bem distintas. Em português elas têm o mesmo significado. Eu uso em português do mesmo jeito que em inglês. Pra mim faz mais sentido e dá mais contexto do que estou falando, é uma forma claramente melhor. Alguém pode dizer que eu estou errado? Não pode porque se pode usar do jeito que quiser então está certo. Ela pode interpretar o que eu disse de forma mais ambígua do que eu quis dizer? Sim, pode, ela não está errada, só está cometendo um outro erro ao fazê-lo porque eu fui mais preciso e ela escolheu jogar fora. Eu posso dizer que ela está errada em tornar ambíguo o que eu fui preciso? Eu não posso. Eu posso dizer que ela foi trouxa de seguir a regra oficial e perder o que ela tinha disponível.

Eu sequer sei dizer o que é um fluxo de controle. Não consegui achar a expressão sendo usada em qualquer outro contexto. É só um erro usar assim ou a programação achou um mecanismo que não tem contraparte em qualquer outra situação do mundo?

Eu posso argumentar, não provar.

O importante que é todos programadores que saibam o mínimo da área vão entender quaisquer dos 3 que você use.

Eu vou continuar dando preferência para Controle de Fluxo, e agora mais ainda, já que parei mais para pensar. Obrigado.

Comment: Quando falei de dissecar fluxo e controle, não estava pensando numa foto de _gamepad_ :P mas sim em ideias como _"o controle é exercido sobre algo, no caso o fluxo"_ ou _"o fluxo se refere ao fluxo de instruções cuja sequência é determinada por certas estruturas"_, coisas assim. E penso que pode-se chamar de estrutura porque esse controle em assembly obedece umas certas estruturazinhas, ou ainda porque em linguagem de alto nível esses comandos _estruturam_ o código de certa maneira de acordo com o fluxo desejado (programação estruturada?). Mas tudo bem, obrigado, ajudou :)

Comment: https://dicionario.priberam.org/estrutura, é uma forma de ver, por isso alguns usam.

Comment: Está certo, pode ser uma disposição, um leiaute. Mais uma vez passando a ideia de dispor ou estruturar o código. Mas vou ver se disseco melhor a Wikipedia em inglês, parece que tem alguma coisa lá, e assim também melhoro a pergunta.